# ORACLE - retrieve deleted data

Tags: sql, oracle

I recently truncated a table by mistake in the wrong environment. It's a huge table saving history 5 years back.

I used `TRUNCATE`, so I can't `undo` / `rollback`.

I tried using flashback:

```
SELECT * FROM STG_SCD_SUB_ACCOUNTS_KEY AS OF TIMESTAMP 
 TO_TIMESTAMP('2016-03-09 09:30:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS')
```

But no luck, produced the error:

> unable to read data - table definition has changed flashback

Any ideas?

Comment: Ask the DBA to restore a back-up. (BTW. Been there, done that...)

Comment: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_01466_unable_to_read_data_table_definition_has_changed.htm

Comment: @jarlh We already called them, waiting for someone

Comment: @DanK Can you elaborate?

Comment: Nervous minutes I suppose... Shouldn't be any problem if the DBA's are doing their work properly.

Comment: what is your Oracle __server__ version?

Comment: @jarlh dba say there is no backup

Comment: You have stated that your error is: `ORA-01466: Unable to read data -- Table definition has changed`. The link provided lists several reasons for reaching this error and courses of action you should take. But honestly, I agree with @jarlh... don't try and solve this yourself. Get your DBA involved. I have no doubt there is a back-up of your table saved somewhere... you may lose a little data but they should be able to restore most of it for you.

Comment: Oracle 11g version

Comment: OK, IMO, in this case your DBAs would have to create an auxiliary DB and perform TSPITR (Tablespace Point In Time Recovery) there for the tablespace(s) containing your truncated table

Comment: @sagi, seriously? no backup?, no standby? no exports/dumps?

Comment: As far as I'm aware your only option/hope is flashback database, but that obviously impacts everything else done since you truncated. Do your DBAs have other ideas? (Or an explanation of why there is no backup, but that's a bit off-topic). Good luck...

Comment: @AlexPoole, what about 1. create restore point, 2. flashback database 3. export/copy/etc.  table 4. go to restore point 5. import table from dump

Comment: @sagi, your DBAs may want to read this Doc ID 1138253.1 on [MOS](https://support.oracle.com)

Comment: Lots of Dev DBs don't get regular backup as they are SUPPOSED to be developer-controlled sandboxes.But on the REAL Data - if not properly backed up and people are given rights to make mistakes then mistakes will happen. Every time. Hopefully it becomes a good learning experience and not a "go find another job" experience for someone....

Comment: No backup but flashback is enabled? See if the DBA can salvage one of your snapshots. But if you truly don't have DB backup you might not necessarily be totally hosed. Check with your server team to see if they are regularly backing up the OS that the DB resides on... it is over my head but I believe you can restore a database from a tablespace file. Otherwise, if it really is worst case then start looking at your upstream data flows... how is this table loaded? Do any upstream systems save export files that you can reload? Any logging that could help you recreate your data?

Comment: There seems to be some good advise here, but you could also try to post your question over at http://dba.stackexchange.com/. Link back to this question so that the suggestions aren't neccessarily repeated.

Answer (score 2):

Since Oracle-10g and beyond Table level flashback feature is enabled by default. Hence the reason we can recover table/index from last DDL time.

```
For ORA-01466 : Unable to read data -- Table definition has changed
cause - the query was executed with a snapshot older than the time the object was changed.
```

since truncate is a DDL one can not be rolled back or recovered using flashback. Only options are to restore full backup or recover tablespace.